# Get subclass instances with abstract methods in Python MyPy

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, type-hinting, mypy

I am trying to get a list of class instances for classes that inherits a particular parent class in Python while using MyPy. I have the following Python classes:

`animal.py`

```
from abc import abstractmethod
from typing import Dict


class Animal():

    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def id(self) -> str:
        pass

    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def sound(self) -> str:
        pass

    def get_all_animals(cls) -> Dict[str, 'Animal']:
        animals : Dict[str, Animal] = {}
        for _class in Animal.__subclasses__():
            animal = _class()
            animals[animal.id] = animal
        return animals
```

`cat.py`

```
from test.animal import Animal


class Cat(Animal):

    @property
    def id(self) -> str:
        return "Cat"

    @property
    def sound(self) -> str:
        "Meow"
```

`dog.py`

```
from test.animal import Animal


class Dog(Animal):
    
    @property
    def id(self) -> str:
        return "Dog"

    @property
    def sound(self) -> str:
        return "Woof"
```

However, in `animal.py` on the line `animal = _class()`, I'm getting the following error:

`Cannot instantiate abstract class "Animal" with abstract attributes "id" and "sound"`

From what I understand, I cannot instantiate instances of `Animal` because there are abstract methods. But in this particular case, I'm only instantiating instances of child classes that have those abstract methods. Is there a way to tell MyPy that `Animal.__subclasses__()` returns types with their abstract method implemented?

Comment: There is an [issue in mypy](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/6199) that seems to be related. It is closed as a duplicate, but [the original issue](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/4717) is still open, and it doesn't look as if there is a solution other then adding a `type: ignore` comment.